# Scenekit automatically inserts underscores for blank spaces in node names when writing to dae

Tags: xml, macos, cocoa, scenekit, collada

I am trying to edit a dae file to change the name of a node. I get the child node which I want to edit, I edit the name which now contains blank spaces - say "Node Name". Once I write this scene to a dae file, using SceneKit's write(to:options:delegate:progressHandler:),
the node name in the new dae file is automatically changing to "Node_Name". Are blank spaces not allowed for node names in dae?

Is there a way to override this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's part of the [Collada 1.4.1 specification](https://www.khronos.org/files/collada_spec_1_4.pdf). A `node`'s `name` is a [`xs:NCName`](http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_NCName.html) and is not allowed to contain whitespaces.

This got relaxed in Collada [1.5.0](https://www.khronos.org/files/collada_spec_1_5.pdf) where `name` becomes a [`xs:token`](http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_token.html).

There's no way to override the Collada specification used by SceneKit, which currently is Collada 1.4.